Can this buffer be used for RF applications like 500 MHz?
I would like to use this buffer suggested by a user named MOSFET from a previous post I made (Why is buffer output signal reduced to half?).

Image source: Answer to "Why is buffer output signal reduced to half?" by MOSFET posted on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange and licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0.
I will try to be as detailed as I can here since I have not in the previous posts. I want to design a buffer for a Hartley oscillator which I plan to make operate at 500 MHz. I want the output of the swing oscillator to be 1V peak to peak. Then I want to pass this through a buffer where the output should stay 1V peak to peak. This buffer is for isolation to prevent the 50 ohm measurement instrument from loading the oscillator.
For the sake of providing details, let us say I want the power supply to be 2.5V. The current through the transistors 1mA. This means the DC power should be 2.5mW. Will this buffer work if use appropriate transistor with high fT (8 GHz for example)?
Here is the schematic on LT SPICE. I am not getting sensible results.



What is preventing you from simulating this circuit and finding out yourself?

i simulated it. didn't work...

I get the impression that you haven't used a simulator before. If so, then learning to use one should be regarded as a more pressing need than this particular question. Simulating over 270 ps is pointless.


Increase V1 from 2.5V to 5V.  2. Show the input voltage V2 as well as the output. 3. Change R3 from 50 to 1k.  Try these changes to get understanding before trying the values you want in your final circuit.


nah that didn't do anything. the problem must be something else.

@xcaliber99 You need to plot Vout vs Vin or Vout vs time. What you plotted doesn't tell whether it's working or not working. One other thing you could try is putting low ohm resistors (~10mOhm) resistors on the emitters of Q1 and Q4.

I say again:  2. Show the sim plot for the input voltage V2 as well as the output voltage vs time.  //  And while you're at it, please include the current in the collectors of Q1, & Q4.  I suspect the bias of the transistors is not sufficient to drive this 50ohm load at the speeds you seek.  Why does your plot stop at ~270ps, it was supposed to run for 5ns.

Added a 39 Ohm resistor to raise the output impedance to 50 Ohm. Voltage gain is 0.5.
Input impedance without considering package (or other) parasitics:
400 Ohm || 1.2pF @ 100MHz
330 Ohm || 1.2pF @ 500MHz


